# I would like to query all focusable elements by React Ref API. How to do this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This library is used for querying focusable elements.
https://github.com/jkup/focusable

### Example of library's code

```
const focusableElements = document.querySelectorAll('a[href], area[href], input:not([disabled]):not([type="hidden"]), [tabindex], ...')
```

But it is query Real DOM.

It may take some web performance drop. So that's why I wanna do it by Ref API instead.

I would like to do the same with that by React Ref API, but I don't know how to do it.

I have to do this for web accessibility reasons.
In an example case, I have several focusable elements on the modal.
And user can use the `Tab` key to through forwarding to the next element.
And when the user uses the `Tab` key on the last, must go to the first element again. (when using `Shift` + `Tab` key on the first must go to the last, too)

### Thing what I want

```
function MyComponent() {
  const elementRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  // How to access every focusable (input, button, and div which it has `tabindex` attr)?
  const focusableElements = elementRef?.current.xxx.yyy.zzz ???


  return (
    <div ref={elementRef}>
      <input />
      <button />
      <section>
        <div tabindex={0} />
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It can't be done using just refs

Comment: This must use only `querySelectorAll()` right?  
I need to use Ref API, coz I wanna deal with updating DOM on Virtual DOM for Web Accessibility reasons (get every focusable element, to get first and last for some users use the `tab` key for their convenience)

Comment: 1. Why do you even need to get all focusable elements? 2. It still cannot be don't using refs.

Comment: for web accessibility reasons, bro.
example case, I have several focusable elements on the modal. And user can use `tab` key to through forwarding to the next element. And when user use `tab` key on the last, must go to the first elem again. (when use `Shift` + `tab` key on the first must go to the last, too)

Comment: Many pages are accessible without grabbing all focusable elements. It's not how accessibility is achieved.

Comment: I edited my last comment for more information about why I need to access every focusable for child elements. you could check out it, bro.

Comment: You are looking for a `focus trap`. You can use [focus-trap-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/focus-trap-react) for example

Comment: Thanks for your solution and kind of your help. I didn't think of any library before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247423/discussion-between-fresult-and-konrad-linkowski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Konrad Linkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089567/konrad-linkowski)'s answer in the comments in my question post.

[Go to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292707/i-would-like-to-query-all-focusable-elements-by-react-ref-api-hot-to-do-this#comment-129681587)

We **can't** use React Ref API for my problem (my problem is looking for Focus Trap).
And then he suggested the solution is, we can use some library such as [focus-trap-react](https://github.com/focus-trap/focus-trap-react) instead.